# Is it required to use a headless service for statefulsets?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-statefulset

Have a couple of question on headless services:

1. Is it required to use a headless service for statefulsets? Can I use the normal service.yml for the stateful sets also?
2. Is it required to use a service & then a headless service? Can I just use headless service instead?
3. Can I not use the pods to attach to the service instead of headless service?

Answer (score 7):

1. You don't have to use a Headless Service technically, but it often makes sense to use one if you want to take advantage of the sticky identity of each Pod in a StatefulSet (i.e. address a specific Pod by name rather than any of the Pods at random as it's the case with a normal Service).
2. Not sure how you mean this. You create a Headless Service by defining a ClusterIP Service and setting the `clusterIP` field to `None`.
3. You can use the Pod names directly too with some tools (e.g. `kubectl port-forward`), but the Headless Service creates DNS names for all the Pods so you can address them in a more general way.

**References:**

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services

Comment: The first referred URL (k8s SS) states explicitly: StatefulSets currently require a Headless Service to be responsible for the network identity of the Pods. You are responsible for creating this Service.

Comment: @Jarek the question was more whether you can technically use a normal service for a StatefulSet. Nothing prevents you from doing so, but you can't take advantage of one of the core features of StatefulSets, the fixed pod identities. If you want to take advantage of this feature, you have to use a headless service.

Answer (score 3):

Headless service doesn't carry any clusterIP, it just takes you directly to the particular pod that you need to communicate to, via its hostname.

Let's take example -

Say you installed kafka statefulset, running 3 brokers in it, now you want to communicate to one broker specifically then that can be done via headless service,

any normal service can do the random distribution of the traffic ( if you have not added any specific affinities in place), the normal service can also do for you, it's all based on use case scenarios